# Node memory leak while using redis brpop

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, memory-leaks, node-redis

I'm having memory leak issue in a node application. The application is subscribed to a topic in redis and on receiving a message pops a message from a list using `brpop`. There are a number instances of this application running in production so one instance might be blocking for a message in the redis list. Here is the code snippet which consumes a message from redis:

```
private doWork(): void {
    this.storage.subscribe("newRoom", (message: [any, any]) => {
      const [msg] = message;
      if (msg === "room") {
        return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
          process.nextTick( async () => {
            const roomIdData = await this.storage.brpop("newRoomList"); // a promisified version of brpop with timeout of 5s
            if (roomIdData) {
              const roomId = roomIdData[1];
              this.createRoom(roomId);
            }
          });
          resolve();
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I've tried debugging the memory leaks using chrome debugger and I've observed too many closure objects getting created. I suspect that it's due to this code as I'm able to see the redis client object name in the closure object but I'm not able to figure out how I might be able to fix it. I added `process.nextTick` but it didn't help. I'm using `node-redis` client for connecting to redis. Attaching an object retainer map screenshot from the chrome debugger tool.

[image: 1]]

P.S. `blk` is the redis client object name used exclusively for blocking commands i.e. `brpop`.

**Edit**: Replaced `brpop` with `rpop` and we're seeing a significant drop in memory growth rate but now the distribution of messages between the workers has gone skewed.

Comment: You don't need a `new Promise` (you already got a few), also why do you need the `process.nextTick`?

Comment: Yes. I've tried both with and without using `Promise`. I just pasted the code with `Promise`. I tried adding `process.nextTick` with the hope that if `brpop` is called at the end of event loop, GC might be able to clear up some space. It was just a blank guess.

Comment: do you unsubscribe?

Comment: No I never unsubscribe.